# Tengo un error "parse error" con php, alguien me podría ayudar?

Tags: php

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\scriptFacturacionCostaRica-master\pdf\documentos\res\ver_factura_html.php
>   on line 212

```
    <style type="text/css">

    table { vertical-align: top; }
    tr    { vertical-align: top; }
    td    { vertical-align: top; }
    .midnight-blue{
       background:#2c3e50;
       padding: 4px 4px 4px;
       color:white;
       font-weight:bold;
       font-size:12px;
   }
   .silver{
       background:white;
       padding: 3px 4px 3px;
   }
   .clouds{
       background:#ecf0f1;
       padding: 3px 4px 3px;
   }
   .border-top{
       border-top: solid 1px #bdc3c7;

   }
   .border-left{
       border-left: solid 1px #bdc3c7;
   }
   .border-right{
       border-right: solid 1px #bdc3c7;
   }
   .border-bottom{
       border-bottom: solid 1px #bdc3c7;
   }
   table.page_footer {width: 100%; border: none; background-color: white; padding: 2mm;border-collapse:collapse; border: none;}
}

</style>
<page backtop="15mm" backbottom="15mm" backleft="15mm" backright="15mm" style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: arial">
    <page_footer>
    <table class="page_footer">
        <tr>

            <td style="width: 15%; text-align: left;font-size:11px">
                P&aacute;gina [[page_cu]]/[[page_nb]]
            </td>
            <td style="width: 85%; text-align: right; color:#696969;font-size:10px">
                &copy; <?php echo  $anio=date('Y'); echo " -  Autorizado mediante resolución #11-97 de la Dirección General de Tributación Directa, publicado en la Gaceta #171 del 5 septiembre de 1997. "; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </page_footer>
    <?php include("encabezado_factura.php");?>
    <br>



    <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 11pt;">
        <tr>
         <td style="width:50%;" class='midnight-blue'>Facturado a:</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td style="width:50%;" >
             <?php 
             $sql_cliente=mysqli_query($con,"select * from clientes where id_cliente='$id_cliente'");
             $rw_cliente=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cliente);
             echo $rw_cliente['nombre_cliente'];
             echo "<br>Cédula: ";
             echo $rw_cliente['cedula'];
             echo "<br>";
             echo $rw_cliente['direccion_cliente'];
             echo "<br> Teléfono: ";
             echo $rw_cliente['telefono_cliente'];
             echo "<br> Email: ";
             echo $rw_cliente['email_cliente'];
             ?>

         </td>
     </tr>


 </table>

 <br>
 <table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 11pt;">
    <tr>
     <td style="width:25%;" class='midnight-blue'>Vendedor</td>
     <td style="width:25%;" class='midnight-blue'>Fecha</td>
     <td style="width:30%;" class='midnight-blue'>Forma de pago</td>
     <td style="width:20%;" class='midnight-blue'>Moneda</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
     <td style="width:25%;">
         <?php 
         $sql_user=mysqli_query($con,"select * from users where user_id='$id_vendedor'");
         $rw_user=mysqli_fetch_array($sql_user);
         echo $rw_user['firstname']." ".$rw_user['lastname'];
         ?>
     </td>
     <td style="width:25%;"><?php echo $fecha_factura;?></td>
     <td style="width:30%;" >
        <?php 
        if ($condiciones==1){echo "Efectivo";}
        elseif ($condiciones==2){echo "Cheque";}
        elseif ($condiciones==3){echo "Transferencia bancaria";}
        elseif ($condiciones==4){echo "Crédito 30 días";}
        ?>
    </td>
    <td style="width:20%;" ><?php if($moneda == 1){ echo "Dólares"; } else { echo "Colones"; } ?></td>
</tr>



</table>
<br>

<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;">
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 10%;text-align:center" class='midnight-blue'>Cantidad</th>
        <th style="width: 60%" class='midnight-blue'>Descripción</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;text-align: right" class='midnight-blue'>Precio Uni.</th>
        <th style="width: 15%;text-align: right" class='midnight-blue'>Precio Total</th>

    </tr>

    <?php
    $nums=1;
    $sumador_total=0;
    $sql=mysqli_query($con, "select * from products, detalle_factura, facturas where products.id_producto=detalle_factura.id_producto and detalle_factura.numero_factura=facturas.numero_factura and facturas.id_factura='".$id_factura."'");

    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
       $id_producto=$row['id_producto'];
       $codigo_producto=$row['codigo_producto'];
       $cantidad=$row['cantidad'];
       $nombre_producto=$row['nombre_producto'];
       $precio_venta=$row['precio_venta'];
    $precio_venta_f=number_format($precio_venta,2);//Formateo variables
    $precio_venta_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_venta_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $precio_total=$precio_venta_r*$cantidad;
    $precio_total_f=number_format($precio_total,2);//Precio total formateado
    $precio_total_r=str_replace(",","",$precio_total_f);//Reemplazo las comas
    $sumador_total+=$precio_total_r;//Sumador

    $total_colones = $row['total_colones'];
    $impuestoValue = $row['impuestos'];
    $cambio = $row['tipo_cambio'];
    if ($nums%2==0){
        $clase="clouds";
    } else {
        $clase="silver";
    }
    ?>

    <tr>
        <td class='<?php echo $clase;?>' style="width: 10%; text-align: center"><?php echo $cantidad; ?></td>
        <td class='<?php echo $clase;?>' style="width: 60%; text-align: left"><?php echo $nombre_producto;?></td>
        <td class='<?php echo $clase;?>' style="width: 15%; text-align: right"><?php echo $precio_venta_f;?></td>
        <td class='<?php echo $clase;?>' style="width: 15%; text-align: right"><?php echo $precio_total_f;?></td>

    </tr>

    <?php 


    $nums++;
}
$impuesto=$impuestoValue;
$subtotal=number_format($sumador_total,2,'.','');
$total_iva=($subtotal * $impuesto )/100;
$total_iva=number_format($total_iva,2,'.','');
$total_factura=$subtotal+$total_iva;
?>

<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 85%; text-align: right;">Subtotal: <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?> </td>
    <td style="width: 15%; text-align: right;"> <?php echo number_format($subtotal,2);?></td>
</tr>
<?php if($impuesto > 0){?>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="widtd: 85%; text-align: right;">Imp. Ventas: <?php echo $impuesto;?>%</td>
  <td style="widtd: 15%; text-align: right;"> <?php echo $total_iva;?></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="width: 85%; text-align: right;">Total: <?php echo $simbolo_moneda;?> </td>
    <td style="width: 15%; text-align: right;"> <?php echo number_format($total_factura,2);?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php if($moneda == 1){ ?>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;margin-top: 0px;border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3">Tipo de cambio: <?php echo number_format($cambio,2);?>&nbsp; Total en colones: <?php echo $total_colones;?></td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: center;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3"></td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: center;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?> 
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;margin-top: 60px;border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">¡Gracias por su preferencia!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 10pt;margin-top: 20px;border:1px;border-color: #778899">
   <tr>
      <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left;"><?php echo get_row('perfil','mensaje_factura', 'id_perfil', 1);?></td>
  </tr>
</table>

</page>
```

Comment: por favor se tan amable de indicarnos donde esta la línea que marca el error

Comment: Cómo te dijeron arriba, marca la línea que te marca error para poder ayudarte, nosotros no sabemos cuál es la linea 212. Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que tu problema esta aquí:

```
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" style="widtd: 85%; text-align: right;">Imp. Ventas: <?php echo $impuesto;?>%</td>
  <td style="widtd: 15%; text-align: right;"> <?php echo $total_iva;?></td>
</tr>
<? } ?> // Error
```

Si te fijas en otras lineas de tu código tienes esa misma llave pero de esta manera:

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; font-size: 8pt;margin-top: 0px;border:none;">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 50%; text-align: left;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3">Tipo de cambio: <?php echo number_format($cambio,2);?>&nbsp; Total en colones: <?php echo $total_colones;?></td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: center;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3"></td>
        <td style="width: 25%; text-align: center;border-top:1px;border-top-color:#D3D3D3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php } ?> //Aqui lo tienes correcto
```

Por lo tanto en el primer fragmento que te he puesto, quedara así:

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="3" style="widtd: 85%; text-align: right;">Imp. Ventas: <?php echo $impuesto;?>%</td>
   <td style="widtd: 15%; text-align: right;"> <?php echo $total_iva;?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?> // abrir y cerrar la etiqueta php correctamente
```